# Fill a new pandas column with row numbers

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DataFrame `data` with random index values:

```
      A   B
100   0   7
203   5   4
5992  0  10
2003  9   8
20   10   5
12    6   2
```

I would like to add a new column 'C' with row numbers. For example:

```
      A   B   C
100   0   7   0
203   5   4   1
5992  0  10   2
2003  9   8   3
20   10   5   4
12    6   2   5
```

Answer (score 142, accepted):

Use [`numpy.arange`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) or `range` by length of `DataFrame`:

```
df['C'] = np.arange(len(df))

df['C'] = range(len(df))
```

Or you can use [`DataFrame.shape`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shape.html), thank you @Mehmet Burak Sayıcı:

```
df['C'] = np.arange(df.shape[0])
```

---

```
print (df)
       A   B  C
100    0   7  0
203    5   4  1
5992   0  10  2
2003   9   8  3
20    10   5  4
12     6   2  5
```

Comment: It is my mistake, I thought that it happens if the `DataFrame` happens to be single column but it turns out it was a `Series` object. I deleted the comment as not to confuse anyone.

Comment: This adds a column at the front with no name AND one at the end called C for me, both auto-incrementing

Comment: @boardtc first column is called index and my solution dont change it. Only add new column `C`

Comment: @jezrael Thanks what I learned was that when reading from a csv pandas auto adds an auto incrementing column as the first column if no index is set!

Comment: is there a way to do this where we could get the row number grouped by A?

Comment: Why not df['C'] = np.arange(df.shape[0])?

Comment: @jezrael `df.shape` is slower:


`len(df) : 456 ns ± 2.47 ns per loop` vs `df.shape[0] : 734 ns ± 12.4 ns per loop`.

Comment: Why not just `range`?

Answer (score 48):

By using `reset_index`

```
df['C'] = df.reset_index().index
df

       A   B  C
100    0   7  0
203    5   4  1
5992   0  10  2
2003   9   8  3
20    10   5  4
12     6   2  5
```

---

To generalise:

```
df['C'] = df.index if df.index.is_monotonic_increasing else range(len(df))
df

       A   B  C
100    0   7  0
203    5   4  1
5992   0  10  2
2003   9   8  3
20    10   5  4
12     6   2  5
```

Comment: That's clever. In case anyone was wondering how that command works, it creates a temporary data frame with a regular/default index (which just numbers rows by default), takes the index from it, discarding the rest of the temporary data frame, and assigns to the original data frame, as a regular column.

Answer (score 13):

We can add new column with row numbers as first column as following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'B': [1, 2, 3], 'C': [4, 5, 6]})

    B   C
0   1   4
1   2   5
2   3   6

df.insert(loc=0, column='A', value=np.arange(len(df)))
    A   B   C
0   0   1   4
1   1   2   5
2   2   3   6
```

Answer (score 5):

Short option without numpy

```
df['C'] = range(len(df))
```

In case you want the row numbers grouped

```
df['C'] = df.groupby('A').cumcount()
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need numpy to achieve the same as in the previous answer:

```
df.insert(loc=0, column="A", value=df.reset_index().index)
```

Comment: You can also use the built-in [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) function like: `df.assign(C=range(len(df)))`